# cleft/emphasis on this sentence: travelling is said to broaden the mind

Tags: clefts

What is the emphasised/cleft transformation of this sentence?

> Travelling is said to broaden the mind.

(I'm going crazy on this one)

Comment: sorry about the spelling mistakes...I meant "cleft/emphasis" and "sentence" they were just typing errors

Comment: You can edit your question, by clicking the edit butten under the question. (they are right under the tags, which is [tag:cleft] in this case). It has already been done though.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "cleft transformation"? As I understand it (having [looked it up here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fHMl4B8M_2wC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=grammar+cleft+transformation&source=bl&ots=6E-OCc6lHz&sig=d-1rHQrazWKaBNSflMou1DoMtv0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAWoVChMIuOX3p7ngxwIVTAnbCh0XkwXz#v=onepage&q=grammar%20cleft%20transformation&f=false)), that would be ***It is** travelling **which** is said to broaden the mind.*

Comment: Fumblefingers, that seems ok to me, but I read somewhere, not on a real textbook, but some notes that you can't use the infinitive like TO BROADEN...but maybe I'm wrong....thanks for your help